# How to download all front page contents (images, css, json, etc.) from a website, protected with javascript challenge

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

Can you help me to make a bash script that will download all website front page contents. Meaning including CSS, JS and Images etc.

**I used these:**

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" -erobots=off --no-parent -P example.com --no-directories -p -A css,js,json,jpeg,jpg,png,html https://www.example.com
```

**And I got index.html only, and what inside on it was these:**

```
</head>
<body><script type="text/javascript"><!--
dbc = function(str){
var hash = 0;
if (str.length == 0) return hash;
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {char = str.charCodeAt(i);hash=((hash<<5)-hash)+char;hash=hash&hash;}
return hash;
}
document.cookie="PPA=" + "61fSBtQLy_fT_R1XlloEQBsKSYsg7rFi" + "; path=/";
document.cookie="CCO=" + dbc("61fSBtQLy_fT_R1XlloEQBsKSYsg7rFi") + "; path=/";
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload() }, 200)
//--></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Is this a one time task?  You could open the page in a browser, answer the challenge and save it after.  From that saved file you would extract the css, images, ... links and wget those.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500 , Yes, its my task and have more than 10 websites to do same thing.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how can I achieved that? Since we have 10 websites that need to check it front page size.

Comment: Because I need to check our website front page size every hour.

Comment: From what I understand, that script creates 2 cookies and reloads the page.  And sets 2 cookies and reloads the page.  And ...  When I put this code in my page that is what it does...  Is that what you want?  Anyway, you could create another page without the challenge, a copy of the original page, that wget will be ok with.  Then add a restriction in your apache to allow only the IP of the machine your wget is running on.

Comment: Sorry, but what I'm trying to do is to download all front page contents from our website. We have 10 websites.

But, the problem is when I used the above wget syntax, waht I've got was the index.html only and inside of that was the above javascript code

Comment: and there's no any files downloaded like, css, html, png, img etc. to display the webpage.

Comment: looks that javascript code blocked my request that's why I didn't get any files.